# What is [htbp] used for?

Tags: floats, optional-arguments

When I try to input a macro for tables or figures, I usually get `[htbp]` beside the command... e.g.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
```

What is the use of it? Can I remove it?

Comment: Yes, you can. Related: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)